# Call stored procedure with Shell Script

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, sqlplus

Can you help me?
How to connect to database Oracle from shell script using sqlplus?
Can you do an example of shell script that call a stored procedure??

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a xxxx.sql file and execute it like this:

```
set serveroutput on;
execute STORED_PROCEDURE;
set serveroutput off;
exit
```

You will need a way to execute your script, I use CRON on *nix based systems.  My script looks something like this

```
#!/bin/sh
# This short shell script calls the XXXX Stored Procedure
# drive.
PATH=$PATH:/opt/oracle/local/bin:/usr/local/bin
export ORACLE_SID=XXXX;   
export ORAENV_ASK=NO;      
export TWO_TASK=XXXXXXXXX;    
. /usr/local/bin/oraenv
sqlplus USERID/PASSWPRD @SQL_Script_to_call_stored_Proceudre.sql
exit
```

Comment: You missed the `@`. Persaonlly I'd also always use the `-s` flag to reduce the noise; and particularly if running from `cron` (though that doesn't seem to be a requirement here) explicitly set the enviromnment: `ORACLE_HOME`, `ORACLE_SID` etc.

Comment: @Alex Poole - You are 100% correct.  I sanitized the example of all that stuff before I posted it.  More out of paranoia that I'll post a password or critical DB name on accident one day.  Ill clean it up now

Comment: It isn't paranoia, they really are out to get you... *8-)

Comment: SQL_Script_to_call_stored_Proceudre.sql is this the same with xxxx.sql??

Comment: @Nick - Yes it's the same

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur - Culd you please tell me what is export twotask in above script?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example:

create an sh file "callProcedureFromBash.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash      this is a comment

#if you can access sqlplus already, you don't need following 2 lines
export ORACLE_HOME = /efs/dist/oracledb/client/10G/exec
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin

sqlplus "userid/password@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = WWW.YOURHOST.COM) (PORT = 12345) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = HXZ524))))" <<END

DECLARE
    a int;
BEGIN
    packagename.Procedurename(a);
END;
/
commit;
```

Comment: Hi can we call a Not stored procedures from a shell script file.(Means directly writing a plsql code) rather than calling the file.